# R Prog- Market Basket Analysis - How to visualize product recommendations while using Support and Confidence Loop?

Tags: r, apriori

```
grid <- expand.grid(support = seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.01),
confidence = seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.01))
```

In this example, the expand.grid is used to increment support metrics from 0.05 till 0.10 with an increment of 0.01. Same for Confidence metric.
Below code [from SO] runs the apriori algorithm to find lift when the above Support and Confidence metrics are met.

Is there a way to visualize all the possible Lifts to help with product recommendations to show?
Thx

```
#SO solution to loop through support,confidence
library(dplyr)
res <- 
grid %>% 
group_by(support, confidence) %>% 
do(model = apriori(
tr,
parameter = list(support = .$support, confidence = .$confidence,maxlen=1)
)) %>% 
mutate(n_rules = length(model)) %>%
ungroup()

View(res$model)
warnings()

summary(res$model[res$confidence == 0.05 & res$support == 0.05][[1]])
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run as `tr` is undefined. You should also specify that the `arules` package is required.

Comment: For context, I'd also add that the code was derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43045512/5805670

Comment: @slamballais absolutely, yes - this link was used. I was supposed to be put in line 2 of the code.

Comment: @AndrewGustar i didn't put the full code but I already have the tr object defined and the code does work. I used https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/market-basket-analysis-r and combined it with this SO thread to loop through minimum support and confidence. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43045512/5805670. I'm just wondering how to visualize it after this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already seen the `arulesViz` [standard plots](https://github.com/mhahsler/arulesViz#standard-visualization), maybe you want to run `arules::inspect` on each model and store outputs? Then you can create a custom plot however you want.

```
library(arules)
id <- c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3")
obj <- c("a", "b", "j", "a", "g","c", "a","k","c")
df <- data.frame(id,obj)
tr <- as(split(df$obj, df$id), "transactions")

grid <- expand.grid(support = seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.01),
                    confidence = seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.01))

library(dplyr)
res <- 
  grid %>% 
  group_by(support, confidence) %>% 
  do(model = apriori(
    tr,
    parameter = list(support = .$support, confidence = .$confidence,maxlen=1)
  )) %>% 
  mutate(n_rules = length(model)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

One option is to use `purrr::map_dfr` to create a single dataframe with all 36 models

```
purrr::map_dfr(res$model, inspect)
```

Or if `arulesViz::plot` is what you are looking for, you can apply it to all 36 models by mapping `plot` to `res$model`. The 36 plots can be put into a single larger plot using `gridExtra`. This is pretty busy by default, but with some customization it might suit your needs.

```
library(arulesViz)
plot_list <- purrr::map(res$model, plot)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
```

Comment: Hi @nniloc, thanks. On saving the output from inspect part of rules, how would this be done in R? If I check the doc, the output from one of the models looks like this https://mhahsler.github.io/arulesViz/README/inspectDT.html.
When I try the plot_list , I'm getting "Error: Can't convert a `gg/ggplot` object to function" while gridExtra command is "Error in arrangeGrob(...) : object 'plot_list' not found".

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you saved a ggplot object called `plot`, effectively overwriting the `plot` function? Since the code was pieced together from a bunch of different places, I'll update the answer with the complete code.

Comment: thanks. I relooked at the code but couldn't find a ggplot that might have overwritten the `plot`